# Visual Studio TableAdapter syntax error on SQL statement

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, datatableadapters

This is getting pretty annoying. This SQL statement runs fine in Access:

```
SELECT payrecords.*, employees.name AS employee
FROM Payrecords 
INNER JOIN employees ON payrecords.employee_id = employees.id
WHERE payrecords.payrun_id = ?
ORDER BY employees.name;
```

But the tableadapter wizard insists there is a syntax error. Even when when I replace the "?" with an actual id it whines. This happens on a number of non-vanilla SQL statements. Sometimes when I ignore the "error" the code runs fine, but sometimes not. This happens in VS 2010 and 2015. Is there a work-around maybe?

Comment: and the actual error message is?

Comment: Instead of showing us what actually works, you should show us what *isn't working*, and the full error message(s) that it spits out.

Comment: Try the same query without the semicolon at the end. I just tried your query in VS2010 and it complained about the ORDER BY clause until I got rid of the semicolon.

Comment: Hmm. Maybe I didn't make it clear that the "error", which should NOT be an error, is in Visual Studio. I showed what worked in Access to prove there was nothing wrong with the query.

Comment: Give Gord a kewpie doll!. Zapped the semi-colon and now Visual Studio is happy. Grr. How do I give you credit for this one?

Comment: One other thing. VS handles the semi-colon just fine on simple, plain vanilla SQL statements. Double grr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TableAdapter query parser in Visual Studio seems to have difficulty dealing with (moderately) complex SQL statements that end with a semicolon (`;`). In this case, simply removing the semicolon from the end of the statement resolved the issue.

Comment: Don't even know how you thought to try this. Especially considering the semi-colon was supplied by VS, not by me. Clearly a bug that has lasted through VS 2015. I can't believe I'm the first person this has happened to.